# Неразрывный пробел

Tags: html

Добрый день!

Имеется конструкция: `длинный текст (5&nbsp;–10&nbsp;Января&nbsp;2015&nbsp;г.)`.
Несмотря на неразрывные пробелы, строка рвется рядом с тире и между цифрой года и сокращением «г.»:

[image: Пример]

Можно ли как-то от этого избавиться?

Comment: CSS

    white-space: nowrap;

Comment: вы хотите одной строкой?

Comment: @Deonis, а если мне надо, что бы слова переносились, а не были сплошной строкой и только определенная пара слов в строке была связкой? Ваш метод тут явно не подходит, читайте зачем нужен неразрывный пробел.

Comment: Ну, как временное решение, заверну в `<span>`. Правда, кажется, `<span>` уже используется где-то, так что еще классы прийдется переработать

Comment: @Alex Krass, вы мне предлагаете почитать, зачем нужен неразрывный пробел? Давайте вместе мочитаем [в официальной документации][1]. Надеюсь, что переводить не нужно? А теперь объясните мне, почему мой метод не подходит, если человек вместо всех пробелов, поставил неразрывный пробел. Для вас это окажется удивительным, но для меня очевидно, что в этой строке (**всей строке**) - переносов быть не должно. Если же ТС хотел какой-либо другой эффект, то это нужно было обозначить в вопросе.

   [1]:http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/specialchars.html

Comment: @Deonis, перевод мне не нужен. У ТС неразрывные пробелы стоят с определенной логикой и выделяют дату. Для меня очевидно, что приведенный "очень-очень длинный текст" перед ней как раз таки должен переносится и рваться, в отличие от единственной даты в скобках, которая должна быть вместе. Использование nowrap как раз таки запретит разрыв этой длинной строки. Вот если бы вы дали более развернутый ответ и указали, что можно текст выделить в span и применить стиль, то было бы другое дело. Если же Вы это и имели ввиду, то видимо я Вас не так понял, а иначе работать не будет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому, что согласно правилам верстки текстовых электронных документов знак тире является точкой разрыва и даже неразрывный пробел тут не поможет. Для этого есть специальный "неразрывный  дефис / non-breaking hyphen" с кодом "&#8209;".

А вот почему рвется между цифрой и сокращением года вопрос, по идее этого быть не должно. По крайней мере мне это воспроизвести не удалось, переносится вся строка.

```
(5&nbsp;&#8209;10&nbsp;Января&nbsp;2015&nbsp;г.).
```

Comment: `&#8209;` дает дефис, а у меня короткое тире. Сравните:

‑ дефис

– которкое тире

— длинное тире

Похоже, в юникоде не предусмотрено специального символа для неразрывных тире.

Comment: @Zelta, не торопитесь с выводом. `&ndash;` — это то, что вам нужно.

Comment: @VenZell, оно переностися хитрее. Слева от тире разрыв запрещен, справа — разрешен. По крайней мере сафари рендерит его так, документацию я, признаюсь, не читал. Это подходит для текста, но не подходит для диапазонов. Вариант со `span`, предложенный выше, меня устраивает

Comment: Это не все виды неразрывных пробелов. Все варианты можно посмотреть тут 
https://domhtml.ru/nerazryvnyj-probel-html/

А вообще, вместо неразрывного пробела лучше использовать вложенные элементы HTML